# Cant figure why theres an error

Tags: vba, excel

When I run the code below sometimes it runs good and most of the time it give me an error message, run-time '91' error (Object Variable or with block variable not set). is there something am missing. please I need your help

```
Sub movedata3()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Set sht2 = Workbooks.Open("\\NMFPLPCLB130010\Public\PACKAGING\tracker.xlsm").Sheets("log") 'set destination sheet as sheet 1 of the opened workbook
    lastRow2 = Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lngLast = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PKG Avail nights") ' reference "source" sheet
        lastRow = .Range("D5:O37").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        With .Range("D:F").Rows("5:" & lastRow) ' reference referenced sheet columns D to F cells from row 5 down to 'LastRow'
            sht2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value ' paste referenced range values to "destination" sheet form column D first empty cell after last not empty one
        End With
        With .Range("K:O").Rows("5:" & lastRow)
            sht2.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHIFT PERFORMANCE DAYS")
                With .Range("AM1")
                    sht2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value
                End With
                With .Range("J1")
                    sht2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Value
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line?  Please indicate the line on which the error is thrown.

Comment: I can almost guarantee your error is related to all of those ugly mis-nested `With`'s. I'd suggested simplifying your code as per "[mcve]".  I cleaned up the code's indentation and spacing.  Maybe take another look and see if those are all nested the way that you intended.  Better yet, remove **all** the `With`'s and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: You guys are right. can you help organize it better. cant find where am missing it

Comment: Get rid of `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHIFT PERFORMANCE DAYS")` and the nested WITH in there. There is no reason for all these `WITH` clauses. They are adding nothing to the code. Just do `sht2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHIFT PERFORMANCE DAYS").Range("AM1").value` for instance.

Comment: You should probably qualify more of your ranges and activity. Example is that you have `lastRow2 = Range("i" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` but you aren't specifying the sheet. This would explain why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, it's looking at the activesheet. There are several instances of this which could be an issue for you. And yes... ditch the WITH statements. Use a variable instead to help keep track.

Answer (score 2):

Okay it took A LOT of deciphering, but I think that I've straightened out what you were doing into a way that doesn't use a ton of `With` statements.

```
Sub movedata3()

    Dim sheetLog As Worksheet
    Dim sheetDays As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNights As Worksheet

    Set sheetLog = Workbooks.Open("\\NMFPLPCLB130010\Public\PACKAGING\tracker.xlsm").Sheets("log") 'set destination sheet as sheet 1 of the opened workbook
    Set sheetDays = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHIFT PERFORMANCE DAYS")
    Set sheetNights = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PKG Avail nights")


    'getting the last non-empty row in "PKG Avail nights"
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sheetNights.Range("D5:O37").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

    'copying from "PKG Avail nights" into the next open cell in "log"
    sheetNights.Range("D5:F" & lastRow).Copy _
        Destination:=sheetLog.Range("D" & sheetLog.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    sheetNights.Range("K5:O" & lastRow).Copy _
        Destination:=sheetLog.Range("G" & sheetLog.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


    'copying from "SHIFT PERFORMANCE DAYS" into the next open cell in "log"
    Dim lastRowD As Long
    lastRowD = sheetLog.Range("D" & sheetLog.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    sheetDays.Range("AM1").Copy _
        Destination:=sheetLog.Range("B" & lastRowD)


    Dim lastRowE As Long
    lastRowE = sheetLog.Range("E" & sheetLog.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    sheetDays.Range("J1").Copy _
        Destination:=sheetLog.Range("C" & lastRowE)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is so much better. Thank you. is it possible to autofill column B and C to the last cell on column D or E.

Comment: Not really. it copied both the formatting and formulas. However, am trying to run away from ".copy statement" but with less "with statements"